# Laravel - Changed password and now I can't login

Tags: laravel

today I changed password via MySql admin and now I get error.
You can see it at:
http://domainsmeca.com/admin/login

I am a designer and not programmer, one friend suggested that I ask here.

Hope some nice person can help me.
Thank you in advance.
Ivonne

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: First of all, remove the link and change the password. It can be seen in plain text. Second, you need to change your `.env` file to match the password (once changed).

Comment: When I got the error, I change it back, but the error is staying :(

Comment: Thank you Ivanka,
The .env file is the same. I even downloaded and checked on my pc

Comment: Have you assigned the user full privileges to the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the password in `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=YourDatabase
DB_USERNAME=urUsername
DB_PASSWORD=Password
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. 
Yes, I know about the this file, but I forgot to make the change here. Instead I made change via MySql (mistake). then when I saw the error I change it back to original again vi MySql, but the error is staying. Then I FTP to my site, downloaded the ,env file and I can see the file hasn't change and it has the original password untouched (the correct one). That's why I am stuck. Unfortunately I am designer and now nothing about programming :(  (but trying to learn)

Comment: Here my env file and it looks file:
# Database Credentials
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=domainsmeca_1
DB_USERNAME=domainsmeca_boss
DB_PASSWORD=cQktR5)Y}gDP   (should I remove it and write again?: Pepsicol@777
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

# Admin Panel Credentials
ADMIN_USER=Boss
ADMIN_PASS=Pepsicol@777

Comment: @Ivonne, if the passwords are correct you need to check the user has full permissions to the database table

Comment: @laravel-levaral
Here my env file and it looks file:
# Database Credentials
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=domainsmeca_1
DB_USERNAME=domainsmeca_boss
DB_PASSWORD=cQktR5)Y}gDP   (should I remove it and write again?: Pepsicol@777
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

# Admin Panel Credentials
ADMIN_USER=Boss
ADMIN_PASS=Pepsicol@777

Comment: Even if I didn't made any other changes?

Comment: @Ivonne. Assign the user full privs to the database table, im fairly sure this is your issue.

Comment: @Ivonne, Within your host control panel under MySQL (where you created the database and the user) you have to assign the user to the database and also assign privileges. Are you using Cpanel?

Comment: yes, cpanel, My SQL but I don't see anything about privileges there. Just rename or delete

Comment: @ivonne, click mysql databases and scroll down to `Add user to database` select the right username and database and then press add. Tick the `ALL PRIVLEGES` box and then press make changes.

Comment: So, should I delete present user completely. Then create new one and use the same information as I have now? Or should I create new user with new info and delete the old user after? I am panicking ;)

Comment: @Ivonne, You should just be able to assign the user: domainsmeca_boss to the database: domainsmeca_1

Comment: That's what I imagine as well and that what I did and worked before. The issue happen when changed the password via MySQL and not via env file. 
I checked again and I don't see where I can change the user privileges. User Boss is still there.. as before and looks fine.

can you be kind enough and check the stuff via my cpanel? If yes I wil give you login info.  PLZ. I am going in the circle.

Comment: I just fix it. It was easy, I just had to do was change in the .env file:
DB_PASSWORD=cQktR5)Y}gDP 
to 
DB_PASSWORD=Pepsicol@777

Comment: Thank you very much for your help